# Android key event generic for all activities

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, key-events

I want below keyevents into all activity.
I have approx 15 activities.

```
    @Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_D:
            moveShip(MOVE_LEFT);
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_F:
            moveShip(MOVE_RIGHT);
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_J:
            fireMachineGun();
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_K:
            fireMissile();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Instead of writing same code into all activity. I want to write it once & use it in all activities.

How can I achieve this scenario?

Comment: Create a Base activity that will be extended by all other activities. Put logic common to all activities in base activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create one BaseActivity which extends Activity where you can put this method.
Extend that BaseActivity all your 15 activities. In all your activities you just need to add :

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  super.onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event);
 }
```

This will call your BaseActivity onKeyUp method.